# Linux Command to set TCP window size

Tags: linux, bash, tcp, sysctl

I want to send TCP packet with window size `65535` (`0xffff`). I m looking to set the TCP window size to 65535 on my linux system.

I know that there is the `sysctl` command but I could not find how tochange the tcp window.

How I can do that on my linux system?

Answer (score 1):

**RHEL:**

```
echo 65535 > /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default

echo 65535 > /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default
```

[Reference](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/01/25/how-can-i-change-the-tcpip-tuning-parameters/)

Comment: 8 years old, and the information is 12 years old. And what exactly is a 'TCP send window'?

Comment: Eh, he wasn't specific about his flavor of Linux

Comment: "TCP Send Window" is where outgoing data is held, in case retransmission is required, until it is ACKd by the other side.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum TCP window size for a socket equals the size of the socket receive buffer, which is set with `setsockopt()` and the `SO_RCVBUFSIZ` option.

Comment: I've answered that. `setsockopt().` If you're asking for a command-line solution you're off-topic: this site is for programming questions.